# Embed an Elm-Element into an existing HTML project

Tags: html, elm

I'd like to render a part of my document in Elm, but the rest of the page already exists.
So I've followed the approach described here:

[Elm HTML/JS integration](https://github.com/evancz/elm-html-and-js)

The Problem here is, that the height and width of the element have to be known beforehand.
But the width of the page is dynamic and the height of the content changes.

Is there a way to at least insert scrollbars?

Thank you very much

---

After applying the first fix here is my minimal example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ghdzl

I could even live with the vertical scrollbar, but the horizontal one is ugly :(

---

Here is my (minimal) code so far:

```
module StandardTexts where

import Window

abstract = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a orci fringilla, rutrum tellus vel, egestas risus. Nunc a sollicitudin orci. Pellentesque congue nec lacus vel fermentum. Sed non nunc ligula. Nulla facilisi. Aenean adipiscing turpis urna, sed pellentesque nulla hendrerit sed. Vestibulum id consectetur urna. Vestibulum congue risus et commodo porttitor. Nullam non lectus sit amet mi varius aliquam quis in dolor. Fusce condimentum blandit interdum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras ornare vitae urna sed porta. Cras dictum libero nulla, ac ultricies lectus dictum vitae. Nullam nec quam id elit bibendum fringilla sit amet eu lacus. Sed sed dui et dolor rhoncus iaculis. Nam id accumsan orci, id facilisis magna."

abstracts w h =  map (always . width w . plainText <| abstract) [0..9]

display (w, h) = container w h topLeft . flow down <| abstracts w h

main = display <~ Window.dimensions
```

Comment: watch this http://elm-lang.org/blog/announce/0.8.elm#embedding-elm-in-html-and-js

Comment: I thought I'd done just this, and I had embedded my code exactly like he did, but it made me think again.
In my code I had set the width of the topmost element to the width of the containing div and thought that would be enough. Not I resize everything and its working. This fixed the problem I had with the width, thanks :)

Comment: so the width changes with the page, and you've found a fix for that? Should Elm be in control of changing the height of the `<div>` you embed it in? Or do you really *want* the vertical scollbar?

Comment: Yes, if you click on this link you can see an example of my current implementation (at least the important parts)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ghdzl

The width is set to 70% of the window width and it works really well.

Ideally the height would be set automatically, without a scrollbar, but I haven't found a way to do this yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised I made a stupid mistake.

I was using the Graphics.Element.container and there was a height set.
Now I can:

- set the height to auto, this wasn't possible before
- remove all calls where I set a height explicitly:

  ```
  display (w, h) = container w h topLeft . flow down <| abstracts w h
  ```

  is now:

  ```
  display (w, h) = flow down <| abstracts w h
  ```

The new code:

```
module StandardTexts where

import Window

abstract = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a orci fringilla, rutrum tellus vel, egestas risus. Nunc a sollicitudin orci. Pellentesque congue nec lacus vel fermentum. Sed non nunc ligula. Nulla facilisi. Aenean adipiscing turpis urna, sed pellentesque nulla hendrerit sed. Vestibulum id consectetur urna. Vestibulum congue risus et commodo porttitor. Nullam non lectus sit amet mi varius aliquam quis in dolor. Fusce condimentum blandit interdum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Cras ornare vitae urna sed porta. Cras dictum libero nulla, ac ultricies lectus dictum vitae. Nullam nec quam id elit bibendum fringilla sit amet eu lacus. Sed sed dui et dolor rhoncus iaculis. Nam id accumsan orci, id facilisis magna."

abstracts w =  map (always . width w . plainText <| abstract) [0..9]

display (w, h) = flow down <| abstracts w

main = display <~ Window.dimensions
```

Example is now here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJaEi

So what I learnt is that as soon as you try to set a height in elm (even if you set it to auto in css) the height will be fixed and you can't change it anymore.

Thank you Rachel Gallen for your help, time and idea that resulted in the fixing of the problem
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/24520426/1829891)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly there's probably a better way of embedding it. there's a video tutorial [here](http://elm-lang.org/blog/announce/0.8.elm#embedding-elm-in-html-and-js).

This gives you a div around your elm element which you can style in your css.

```
  overflow:auto;
```

will introduce scroll bars but you can style to adjust the height and width to your needs

Comment: This, together with your comment to my question creates a problem. I managed to fix the width of the elements, so that they exactly fit into my div, but when I do
    overflow: auto

A scrollbar is created on the right hand side, that makes the container smaller and a scrollbar has to be put on the bottom too :(

Would you know a way to fix the height problem all together? (without a scrollbar?)

Thank you for your answer